# Выделение памяти под строку

Tags: c, дерево

Есть бинарное дерево. Узлы которого - char * data;
На вход - строки из файла(str). Узел - слово(data). char * data
Пишу:

```
while (fgets(str, 800, LP))
 {
    int i = 0;
    int size = strlen(str);
    while (i<size)
    {
        char *tmp = (char *)calloc(80, sizeof(char));
        int j = 0;
        while ((str[i] >= 'А' && str[i] <= 'Я') || (str[i] >= 'а' && str[i] <= 'я'))
            tmp[j++] = tolower(str[i++]);
        i++;
        if (strlen(tmp) > 2) {
            root = AddNode(tmp, root);
        }
    }
    }
```

Ну, и собственно по понятным причинам, у меня на выходе получается только один элемент в дереве, из-за того что каждый раз указатель на строку tmp имеет новое значение

Но вот как исправить, чтобы сохранить структуру дерева (т.е. чтобы у узла так и осталась строка char * data)

Comment: И что, это работает в разных локалях?

Comment: По заданию русский язык нужен. Ко мне какие претензии быть могут? 
Да, может что-то не совсем рационально, опыта пока мало.

Comment: Да у вас переносимости просто ноль у этих строк кода. Так не-ASCII буквы не проверяют. Ох, там данные из файла, это ещё на порядок веселее. Необходимо учитывать mime type и encoding файла ещё...

Comment: 1. Да у вас переносимости просто ноль у этих строк кода. О: Ну так подскажите как нужно в таком случае.
2. Необходимо учитывать mime type и encoding файла ещё..
О: Вы так говорите, как будто это в реальный проект уйдет. Про всё это я слышу впервые. Следовательно, учитывать это необходимости нет. Если в каждом задании учитывать абсолютно все нюансы, то на одно задание будет уходить слишком много времени. Я делаю по мере возможностей и требований

Comment: 1. Могу намекнуть, но поля для комментариев явно не для развёрнутых дискуссий. 2. Вы так говорите, как будто "тяп-ляп и в продакшн" ваше будущее кредо.

Comment: По первому пунтку, если коротко, то читайте странички документации на такое: `setlocale()`, `towlower()`, `mbrtowc()`.

Comment: Самое забавное в вашем коде, если вы его набирали в кодировке UTF-8 (или любой неоднобайтовой).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то просто нужно заменить строку

```
char *tmp = (char *)calloc(800, sizeof(char));
```

на строку копирования строки

```
char *tmp = strdup(temp);
```

`strdup` внутри вызовет `malloc`, выделит достаточно памяти и скопирует туда строку. Освобождать такую память нужно привычным `free(tmp);`

исходный код [strdup](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-186/string.subproj/strdup.c) подскажет, как это все происходит (он правда написан на старом си.

```
char *
strdup(str)
    const char *str;
{
    size_t len;
    char *copy;

    len = strlen(str) + 1;
    if (!(copy = malloc((u_int)len)))
        return (NULL);
    bcopy(str, copy, len);
    return (copy);
}
```

Можно конечно и ручками написать выделение-копирование, но зачем?

Да, и главное не забыть поправить строку

```
root = AddNode(tmp,root);
```

и добавить вызовы free по необходимости.

**upd**

код вытянут с коментариев

```
char * tmp;
while ((tmp = strtok(str, " ,.-?!"))) {
 if(strlen(tmp)>2)
   root = AddNode(strdup(tmp), root); 
}
```

надо понимать две вещи. конструкция вида `char * tmp = str;` не копирует строку, а только указатель (то есть, скорее всего 4 байта). и после этого два указателя указывают на одну и ту же область памяти. Второе - strtok **модифицирует** исходную строку.

Comment: Код то что я привел, с ошибками :(( 
Торопился..
Суть в следующем:
Есть многострочный текст в файле:
Из файла берется строка str на 800 символов.
Из данной строки, последовательно берутся слова. 
Слово заносится в char * tmp.
После определенной проверки, заносится в дерево.
Потом цикл повторяется, и берется новое слово из той же строки.

Да, копирование должно исправить проблему, но вопрос только, где его вставить нужно.

Comment: может использовать strtok?

Comment: Можно и strtok. Тут скорее проблема после вставки элемента в дерево, при следующей вставке не потерять предыдущее слово..

Comment: нужно просто результат, возвращаемый strtok завернуть в strdup.

Comment: Давайте может без strtok, чтобы я окончательно не запутался.

   char * tmp =str;
   while (tmp)
   {
    tmp = strdup(str = strtok(str, " ,.-?!"));
    if(strlen(tmp)>2)
    root = AddNode(tmp, root);
   }

Comment: ` char * tmp =str;` не копирует строку. Только указатель. В свете этого всего вся конструкция стает странной.

Comment: Почему-то tmp = strtok(str, " ,.-?!") затирает строку str, в итоге там остается только 1 слово.

Comment: ещё раз - strtok МОДИФИЦИРУЕТ исходную строку.